# How to count number of bytecodes executed in java

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

I'm going to enter MIT's battlecode competition. The entrants write programs that control robots that fight each other. The catch is that your robots are limited to executing a certain amount of bytecode in a turn (last year it was 10000 per turn). Now, a simple loop
like

```
(int i=0; i<100; i++){
// do nothing
}
```

uses, according to their software, approximately 400 bytecode (presumably something like
(2 bytecode for incrementing i plus 2 bytecode
for checking if i<100) * 100 = 400 bytecode) so we have to write very tight code.  Hence, as I try out some different navigation algorithms its important that I be able to figure out how much bytecode my code is using -- how can I do this?

(It IS possible -- they do it, I'm just not sure how! Also, they must stop the JIT from coming into play somehow. I know that each robot is run in a separate Thread, so I'm sure
the answer involves some sort of Thread trickery I don't know about.)

Comment: If you're being measured by the number of instructions executed, you'll probably want to write the bytecode by hand. The Java Compiler blindly translates your source into bytecode without optimization, meaning that it has tons of redundant instructions. Ordinarily this wouldn't be a problem since the VM optimizes them away, but it will increase your instruction count. You can do a lot better by writing bytecode directly.

Comment: This post[e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70103878/how-to-count-the-number-of-executed-bytecodes-of-a-java-program/70114683#70114683) gives a working code snippet for this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking over [their source code](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-370-the-battlecode-programming-competition-january-iap-2013/pages/specs-and-software/), they use the asm bytecode manipulator http://asm.ow2.org/ to do the counting.

Comment: Unfortunately the link is not available

Comment: modern iterations available here https://github.com/orgs/battlecode/repositories

Answer (score 6):

You can get the count by using a debug build of the Hotspot JVM (which can be found [here](http://download.java.net/jdk6/6u25/promoted/b03/index.html)) and running it with the `-XX:+CountBytecodes` flag.

Comment: If I download that and run it on a class file compiled by javac 1.7.0_09 I get an error "Unsupported major.minor version 51.0". Is there a different compiler I should be using?

Comment: well, I did link to a java 6 vm, so that's not surprising :) I'm not aware of a debug build of the java 7 vm that's available online, so your best bet is to install the java 6 compiler and recompile. Alternatively, you could compile the java 7 vm on your own, but I think that'd be more of a hassle.

Comment: You'll also have to specify -XX:-UseCompiler or else the code will get compiled to native and then it won't get counted.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate your bytecode like this:

```
javac Employee.java
javap -c Employee > Employee.bc
```

Source: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibm/library/it-haggar_bytecode/