# How to count the number of executed Bytecodes of a java program?

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I am trying to write a simple program using Java [ASM](https://asm.ow2.io/asm4-guide.pdf) to count the number of executed Java Bytecodes.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811082/how-to-count-number-of-bytecodes-executed-in-java) asks the same thing, and has a solution to use ASM. However, the answer points to a link that is no longer available.

I explored the Java ASM API, found the Tree Based API which seems to allow this task. The following is what I have achieved so far.

```
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter;
import org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes;
import org.objectweb.asm.tree.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class Executor {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Contract c = new Contract();
        c.execute();

        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("target/classes/Contract.class");

        ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(is);
        ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);

        final ClassNode classNode = new ClassNode();
        cr.accept(classNode, 0);
        classNode.fields.add(new FieldNode(Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC,
                "Counter", "I", null, new Integer(-1)));


        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("target/classes/ModifiedContract.class");
        classNode.accept(cw);
        fos.write(cw.toByteArray());
        fos.close();
    }


}
```

What I have achieved so far is to add a global counter to a .class file (bytecode).

To my understanding the next step is to add a counter++ statement after each bytecode executed.

From the documentation I found that `InsnList` object in the MethodNode correspond to a bytecode: is this correct?

If so what is the best way I can add a counter++ statement for each bytecode, so that at the end I get the number of Bytecodes executed (I am not interested in the total number of Bytecodes, but only the executed Bytecodes)

(I am new to the Java + ASM world)

Thanks

Comment: Don’t you want to declare the field as `static`? Further note that specifying a constant value is pointless here, as the field is not constant. If you want an initial value for a mutable field, you have to assign it in the constructor (or class initializer if the field is `static`). But why not use the default value of zero, which is a suitable initial value for a counter? Then, incrementing a `static` field consists of four instructions, `getstatic`, `iconst_1`, `iadd`, `putstatic`, whereas incrementing a non-`static` field requires six: `aload_0`, `getfield`, add one, `aload_0`, `putfield`.

Comment: @Holger thank you for the comment. I think you are correct that I should declare it as a class variable - static. I am not sure I understood correctly your approach to increase the static counter. Can you please give a code snippet?

Comment: Generally, when you want to do bytecode manipulation, you should know [The Java® Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/index.html). Chapter 6 describes all bytecode instructions, but chapter 3 is also valuable, as it shows how high-level constructs map to these instructions. And it never hurts to know about the other stuff in the other chapters…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An elaboration of the comment from @Holger

```
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter;
import org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes;
import org.objectweb.asm.tree.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class Executor {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Contract c = new Contract();
        c.execute();

        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("target/classes/Contract.class");

        ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(is);
        ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);

        final ClassNode classNode = new ClassNode();
        cr.accept(classNode, 0);
        classNode.fields.add(new FieldNode(Opcodes.ACC_STATIC +Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC, "count", "I", null, 0));


        for (final MethodNode mn :classNode.methods) {

            ListIterator<AbstractInsnNode> itr = mn.instructions.iterator();

            // core insert
            while (itr.hasNext()) {

                AbstractInsnNode node = itr.next();

                InsnList numCounting = new InsnList();

                // insert count++
                numCounting.add(new FieldInsnNode(Opcodes.GETSTATIC, classNode.name, "count", "I"));
                numCounting.add(new InsnNode(Opcodes.ICONST_1));
                numCounting.add(new InsnNode(Opcodes.IADD));
                numCounting.add(new FieldInsnNode(Opcodes.PUTSTATIC, classNode.name, "count", "I"));

                // insert callme
//            numCounting.add(new MethodInsnNode(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, "com/lvxiaoxin/staticDemo", "callme", "()V", false));

                mn.instructions.insert(node, numCounting);
            }
        }


        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("target/classes/Contract.class");
        classNode.accept(cw);
        fos.write(cw.toByteArray());
        fos.close();
    }


}
```

Basically this would add a count++ statement after each bytecode executed.

As an example consider the following class as the original java class.

```
public class Contract {
    private double Cvar1;
    private float Cvar2;
    private char Cvar3;
    private String Cvar4;
    private int Cvar5;
    private long Cvar6;

    public Contract(){}

    public void execute(){
        double var1 = 0.1;
        float var2 = 0.1F;
        char var3 = 'a';
        String var4 = "a";
        int var5 = 1;
        long var6 = 2;
        System.out.println("Executing the contract");
    }


}
```

Now if this class is compiled, and the resulting Bytecode file is modified using the Executor, the following Decompiled class is generated.

//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
//

```
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Contract {
    private double Cvar1;
    private float Cvar2;
    private char Cvar3;
    private String Cvar4;
    private int Cvar5;
    private long Cvar6;
    public static int count;

    public Contract() {
        ++count;
        ++count;
        ++count;
        super();
        ++count;
    }

    public void execute() {
        ++count;
        ++count;
        ++count;
        double var1 = 0.1D;
        ++count;
        ++count;
        ++count;
        ++count;
        float var3 = 0.1F;
        ++count;
        ++count;
        ++count;
        ++count;
        boolean var4 = true;
        ++count;
        ++count;
        ++count;
        ++count;
        String var5 = "a";
        ++count;
        ++count;
        ++count;
        ++count;
        boolean var6 = true;
        ++count;
        ++count;
        ++count;
        ++count;
        long var7 = 2L;
        ++count;
        ++count;
        ++count;
        PrintStream var10000 = System.out;
        ++count;
        ++count;
        var10000.println("Executing the contract");
        ++count;
        ++count;
        ++count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that since you didn’t introduce new branches or local variables, you don’t need the rather expensive `COMPUTE_FRAMES` option; the original frames are already sufficient. `COMPUTE_MAXS` will do here. Further, use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for the `FileInputStream` and especially the `FileOutputStream`. Or use [`Files.readAllBytes(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes(java.nio.file.Path)) and `Files.write(Path, byte[], …)` in the first place.